# remover [] da lista de array

Tags: php, json, array

eu tenho um arquivo php que gera um json em array para uma outra aplicação ler, entretanto tudo esta funcionando mas o json esta vindo com as [] da lista, e minha aplicação só consegue ler a partir das {}, tem como remover antes de gerar o json as [] ?

Codigo que gera o json

```
<?php

$result = $con->query($Sql_Query);

$rows = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


    array_push($rows, $row);

}
<br>
$json = json_encode($rows);
<br>
$file = 'file.json';
<br>
file_put_contents($file, $json);
<br>
 mysqli_close($con);
<br>
?>
```

Resultado do json

```
[{"ID":"10","name":"name","email":"email@hotmail.com","id_user":"12345"}]
```

Comment: se é um array sempre vai vir com `[]`, com `{}` só se for um único objeto, acho que precisa mudar a sua aplicação que lê, pq ela está esperando um único objeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifica se o resultado do `mysqli_fetch_assoc` tem mais de um elemento, se tiver mais de um elemento faz o fluxo que já estava acontecendo, se não, atribui o primeiro e único elemento na variavel `$rows`

```
<?php

$result = $con->query($Sql_Query);

$rows = [];

if(count(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) > 1){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        array_push($rows, $row);

    }

} else {

    $rows = array_shift(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));

}

<br>
$json = json_encode($rows);
<br>
$file = 'file.json';
<br>
file_put_contents($file, $json);
<br>
 mysqli_close($con);
<br>
?>
```